# wordpress plugin not able to display forms one beside another

Tags: php, css, wordpress, forms, display

I m trying to develop a wordpress plugin which has got two forms in the admin section. Everything seems to be working fine except for the display property that I set. No matter what I do, the two forms will be displayed one below the other whereas I want them to be displayed one beside the another.
This is my code:

```
echo "<div style='display:inline; border:1px solid black;'><h2>Use this form to allocate cash to a client</h2><br/>";
echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'>............</form></div>";
```

I did this with both the forms, but it isnt working, even the borders are not visible. Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you specifying any CSS for that `<h2>` tag? Otherwise you will get browser-injected `<h2>` styling which includes `display:block` Also, run the plugin and open the page where the forms are not plying nice and use your browser dev tools to inspect them.

Comment: @ I Love CSS  no I didnt specify any other css apart from this. I will try now.

Comment: Also, use `style="#"` instead of  `style='#'` -  double Quotation marks instead of single

Comment: @ I Love CSS Even after following both steps problem still remains, I styled h2 and form with display inline (I needed to put <br> tags to give line breaks between heading and form elements).

Comment: What happens if you remove the <br>

Comment: @ I Love CSS Then everything is displayed in a single line